# Are there studies on the effect of reduced CO2 levels on human cognition?

Tags: cognition

I see studies that indicate elevated CO2 levels (>>400ppm) can cause cognitive impairment.

Are there also studies that investigate the effects of cognition under low CO2 levels (<<400ppm)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any biological basis for such a study.

CO<sub>2</sub> is produced as a waste product of metabolism and exists in the blood and lungs at [levels far higher than atmospheric levels (~100X)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonary_gas_pressures). Relative to the air in the lungs, the atmospheric concentration of CO<sub>2</sub> might as well be zero.

Very high atmospheric CO<sub>2</sub> (relative to normal atmospheric levels) can have cognitive effects (among others) because it prevents CO<sub>2</sub> clearance from the lungs and therefore increases blood CO<sub>2</sub> (hypercapnia) and can cause respiratory acidosis.

Comment: Here's another good reference that supports what Bryan says here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breathing

Comment: I guess impaired gas exchange makes sense for very high concentrations. Also in some studies high CO2 might correlate with cognitive effects due to confounders.